# Dynamically read XML file and convert into CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to this python world and I need help on reading XML files.

I have deeply nested XML files which needs to be converted into CSV using python.

In that code, I don't to use any hard coded value (attribute name or Tag name) everything has to be dynamic in nature.

And also I want to include 3 parent tag name in the column header.

### **Few lines of my XML:**

```
*<Seat_Assist>
        <Seat_Assistt Changed="N" EndAirportCode="CCCRLT" Id="2292" ProviderPaxRef="1.01" SegNo="1" SmokingPreference="Y" StartAirportCode="SOITMF" StatusCode="HS">
            <SeatLocation Id="08B">
                <SeatAttrib Code="HRS" Description="OPEN SEAT"/>
                <SeatType>YA</SeatType>
                <SeatTypeExpanded>ARHMI</SeatTypeExpanded>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="A" Description="AISL SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="R" Description="RIGH SIDE SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="H" Description="HAND APPED SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="M" Description="MEDI L OK SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="I" Description="INFA  SEAT"/>
            </SeatLocation>
            <Status StatusCode="HK"/>
        </Seat_Assistt>
        <Seat_Assistt Changed="N" EndAirportCode="DWX" Id="224" ProviderPaxRef="1.01" SegNo="2" SmokingPreference="Y" StartAirportCode="CT" StatusCode="HRS">
            <SeatLocation Id="21D">
                <SeatAttrib Code="VRS" Description="HOLDS SEAT"/>
                <SeatType>YA</SeatType>
                <SeatTypeExpanded>ARHMI</SeatTypeExpanded>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="A" Description="AISLE SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="R" Description="RIGHT SIDE SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="H" Description="HANDICAPPED SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="M" Description="MEDICAL OK SEAT"/>
                <SeatCharacteristic Code="I" Description="INFANT SEAT"/>
            </SeatLocation>
            <Status StatusCode="HK"/>
        </Seat_Assistt>
    </Seat_Assist>*
```

---

**I have only 3 requirement:**

1. Column name in the csv file should be like below
   "parentTagName_subParentTagName_childTagName_keyname" in case of key value
   "parentTagName_subParentTagName_childTagName_text" in case of no key only text

   **Column name in csv file**:  "Seat_Assistt_SeatLocation_SeatCharacteristic _Code"
2. If in the same tag, key are getting repeated then it should not create a column. only append as a new row.
   For Example: In the above code key ="Code" is getting repeated the this should create only one column and append all the value to it like,

Seat_Assist_Seat_Assistt_SeatLocation_Id     Seat_Assistt_SeatLocation_SeatCharacteristic _Code

08B                                           A
08B                                           R
08B                                           H
08B                                           M
08B                                           I
21D                                           A
21D                                           R
21D                                           H
21D                                           M
21D                                           I

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the reading XML part of the problem, start here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

Comment: Thank you for your post. However, we also have requirements: [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) and [mcve]. Please make an earnest attempt at solution so we can help in your learning curve.

Comment: @mzjn, As I said, I am new to this python, if you could please help me with code please.